# gwt junit for testing objectify

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, junit, objectify

I am trying to test my gwt app with gwt junit but seems to not be able to set up things correctly to make the objectify be tested.
All the tutorials demonstrate testing DataStore but not objectify (which is higher level of data base service)
My base class for testing looks like this:

```
public class TestBase {
private static final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
    new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
protected static ObjectifyFactory fact;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
    fact = new ObjectifyFactory() {
        @Override
        public Objectify begin(ObjectifyOpts opts)
        {
            opts.setSessionCache(false);
            return super.begin(opts);
        }
    };

}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
}

}
```

then i have classes that extends the base:

```
public class UserServiceTest extends TestBase{
private User inactiveUser;
private UserService us;
Objectify _ofy;

@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();


@Before
public void beforeTest() {   

    //Register the classes used in the test
    fact.register(User.class);


    us = new UserService();
    inactiveUser = new User();

}   

@Test
public void basicTest(){
    Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();
    ofy.put(inactiveUser); //This fails with exception: An exception occurred: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException 

            //My goal is to reach these test but "addUser" uses also objectify
    //UserService.addUser("shpungin@gmail.com", "bye");
    //assertNotNull(inactiveUser.get_id());
}
```

Do you have an idea of what am I doing wrong? I looked all over the Internet and found no solution (some even said to remove app-engine-sdk from .classpath but it dosent seems to work.

Thank you.

Comment: How is this related to GWT? I only see plain JUnit, AppEngine and Objectify here.

Comment: Hi Thomas, My project is a gwt project and I am running gwt junit test.

Comment: Well, this is a JUnit 4 test, not a GWTTestCase, so it can hardly be called a "gwt junit test"; it's just a plain JUnit test, there's nothing GWT-related in it; it doesn't really matter whether you use GWT in the same project or not as far as this test is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this.

Although com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy should be part of the app-engine
Some jars still needs to be inside the .classpath :

${SDK_ROOT}/lib/testing/appengine-testing.jar

${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar

${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar

${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar //This one I missed

Also I upgraded my app-engine to v 1.6.4.1 (maybe that also helped).